# How can I access the body parameters from a POST request using only the internal HTTP module from NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, http

I'm trying to access the body parameters from the request using only the http internal module from NodeJS. I've looked up everywhere and I can't seem to find how to do that other than using express or some other library. I know that with express you do that by simply using req.body.myparameter. Can I do it only with http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will then need to handle data Buffer manually:

```
if (req.method === 'POST') {
    let body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => { //start reading data
        body += chunk.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        console.log(body); //logging submitted data
        res.end('ok');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was what I needed back when I faced this problem.